# using flatMap to enumerate SpriteKit nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I tried using the following to get all nodes of a certain class:

```
let enemies = children.flatMap { $0 as? SomeEnemyClass }
```

The result is an empty array. I would like to understand why I'm not getting any results. enumerateChildNodesWithName works, but it doesn't list the parent/child relationships which I thought might shed some light. Thanks!

Here is the code: There is a simple class for the enemy, a level manager that replaces nodes in the scene editor with enemy objects, and GameScene.swift. Everything gets assigned to a world node.

**Enemy Class**

```
class Enemy: SKSpriteNode {
   func spawn(parentNode:SKNode, position: CGPoint, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)) {
      parentNode.addChild(self)
      self.size = size
      self.position = position
      self.name = "enemy"
      self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: size.width / 2)
      self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
      self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy.rawValue
      self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.hero.rawValue
      self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
   }
}
```

**Level Manager**

```
    class LevelManager
    {
       let levelNames:[String] = ["Level1"]
       var levels:[SKNode] = []

       init()
       {
          for levelFileName in levelNames {
             let level = SKNode()
             if let levelScene = SKScene(fileNamed: levelFileName) {
             for node in levelScene.children {
                switch node.name! {
                   case "enemy":
                   let enemy = Enemy()
                   enemy.spawn(level, position: node.position)
                   default: print("Name error: \(node.name)")
                }
             }
           levels.append(level)
          }
       }
   func addLevelsToWorld(world: SKNode)
   {
      for index in 0...levels.count - 1 {
         levels[index].position = CGPoint(x: -2000, y: index * 1000)
         world.addChild(levels[index])
      }
   }
 }
```

**GameScene.swift - didMoveToView**

```
world = SKNode()
world.name = "world"
addChild(world)

levelManager.addLevelsToWorld(self.world)
levelManager.levels[0].position = CGPoint(x:0, y: 0)
```

Comment: Please can you show us more of your code? The line you've posted works fine for me.

Comment: I have added the code - thanks for looking. If there is an obvious problem that's great. If not, what I'm hoping for are some thoughts on how to figure the problem out. I've read all the google results, checked the documentation, and tried about a thousand variations, but nothing is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I learned was that the node tree is really a tree and you have to start looking on the right branch to get results. The answer to my question is:

```
let enemies = childNodeWithName("//level")!.children.flatMap { ($0 as? SomeEnemyClass) }
```

or

```
let enemies = childNodeWithName("//level")!.children.filter { $0 is SomeEnemyClass }
```

This is not an answer to my question, but it works too...

```
 self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("//*") {
       node, stop in
       if (node.name == "enemy") {
          print(node)
       }
    }
```

Thank you to everyone who offered their input. It got me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

`map` and `flatMap` transform one array into another, what you are really trying to do is just filtering your child nodes for enemies. Use `filter` instead.

```
let enemines = children.filter { $0 is SomeEnemyClass }
```

That said, I don't see any reason why your sample code would not work.

Here is an example of this code working.
[image]

This code will only work if you have real classes derived from `SKNode`. It is much more common to use node name strings to identify types of nodes. This would work if you had a constant string name for your enemies.

```
let enemies = children.filter { $0.name == "SomeEnemy" }
```

Comment: `filter` doesn't typecast though, which I suspect is what OP wants, otherwise you'll have to force downcast the elements – which could get ugly.

Comment: Interesting point but I would bet that both the OP's and this enemies array would still be inferred as type `SKNode`; the type of the `children` array.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the `flatMap` signature, you'll see that the type of the output array is dependant on the type that you return in the closure. In this case OP is conditionally downcasting to `SomeEnemyClass`, therefore the type returned from the closure will be `SomeEnemyClass?` – and because `flatMap` filters out nil, the resultant array will be `[SomeEnemyClass]`. With `filter` you'll just get out the same type of array as you put in, i.e `[Foo]` in your case.

Comment: You are right. Using `is` creates a filtered array of `SKNode` (base class) while `as?` returns an array of the `SomeEnemyClass`.

Comment: @PriceRingo: as _@originaluser2_ explained, the OP does not need `filter`. He needs `flatMap` because he wants the return type to be `[Enemy]`.

Answer (score 1):

You said

> ```
> let enemies = children.flatMap { $0 as? SomeEnemyClass }
> ```
>
> The result is an empty array. I would like to understand why I'm not getting any results. enumerateChildNodesWithName works

First of all this code

```
let enemies = children.flatMap { $0 as? Enemy }
```

is correct and it does returns an array of `Enemy`. Specifically all objects inside `children` that are `Enemy` or subclasses of `Enemy`.

### Look

[image]

### Why is not working for you?

You said that `enumerateChildNodesWithName` si working for you. This makes me think that you don't have `Enemy` objects into children. You just have `SKNode(s)` you assigned the name `enemy`.

Comment: Well, now we're getting somewhere. If I print enemies.count in my app I get 0. So, I printed world.children. There are plenty of SKSpriteNodes, but no enemies. Which (if I'm staring to understand this) means that my enemies are the children of a different node. But which one? My level manager creates a level node and adds the enemies to that. The level node then gets added to the world node. Taking all of that into consideration, how would I reference the children of the level node which is a child of the world node using flatMap? Or filter...

Comment: @squarehippo10: Looking at your code I see that `Enemy` is never added to the scene graph. You create an enemy with `let enemy = Enemy()` and then you invoke `enemy.spawn(level, position: node.position)` but you never add it to the scene. The problem here is that there is no `Enemy` into your scene.

Comment: I believe that Enemy gets added in didMoveToView in GameScene.swift when the addLevelsToWorld function is called.  In the scene editor I use color sprites and give them a name and a texture.  That way I can place enemies visually using the editor. The spawn function then replaces the color Sprites with an actual instance of the correct class based on its name. I appreciate your help. I feel like I'm much closer to understanding what is going on and will keep working on it.